# How to align left html_document rendered by rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, alignment, r-markdown

Since I am not familiar with css I was wondering if there is a simple way to "tell" my rmarkdown page to left align when rendering an HTML-page?

Something like this:

```
---
title: "My html-page"
output:
 html_document:
  body_placement: left 
---
```

Comment: You could add `css: mystyles.css` and put something like `body { text-align:left; }`, if that's what you want. However, it is already left aligned by default, so you may mean sth different...

Comment: I think I was not clear. I meant the whole body to be left aligned. Now the body is centered.

Comment: Do you care about using the default "boostrap" theme? If not, then you can just do `theme: null` where you currently have `body_placement: left`.

Comment: thanks @hrbrmstr! Nice alternative solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
---
title: "My html-page"
output: html_document
---
<style>
body {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd actually like some basic styles (i.e. not my `theme:null` suggestion), grab [Skeleton](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/releases/download/2.0.4/Skeleton-2.0.4.zip) and put `normalize.css` & `skeleton.css` in the same directory as your Rmd file. Then you can do:

````
---
title: "Title"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: null
    css: 
      - normalize.css
      - skeleton.css
    keep_md: true
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
---

One

Two

```{r}
print("three")
```
````

which will result in:

You can add a third `- my.css` if you want to customize it a bit more.

[image]