# How can I align the html output of a Rmd file to the left

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

when I knit to html a Rmd file the output I visualize on my browser is always centered.
How can I justify everything to the left so there is no wasted space ?
By wasted space I mean there is space on the left of the TOC that is unused

EDIT
I am aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897498/how-to-align-left-html-document-rendered-by-rmarkdown) but I want to keep the TOC, what I really want is equivalent to move everything to the left so the TOC is next to the left-justified

code:

````
---                                                                        
title: "Example SO"                                                        
output:                                                                    
  html_document:                                                           
    toc: true                                                              
    number_sections: true                                                  
    code_folding: "hide"                                                   
    toc_float:                                                             
      collapse: false                                                      
      smooth_scroll: false                                                 
---                                                                        

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}                                                   
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE,                                        
                      echo = TRUE,                                         
                      message = FALSE,                                     
                      comment = "",                                        
                      fig.align = "left"                                   
                      )                                                    
```                                                                        

# H1 Stuff                                                                 

```{r, DT}                                                                 
    DT::datatable(mtcars, rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 2))
```                                                                        

# H2 More stuff                                                            
Bla
````

output:
[image: output]

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I understand your definition of wasted space. However, you have a floating TOC in your Rmd file, so there will be space on the left reserved for this.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897498/how-to-align-left-html-document-rendered-by-rmarkdown ?

Comment: None of this seems to be working for me because it overrides the default theme, I want to keep the TOC but move it the left as much as possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the "centered" behavior is because of CSS, specifically the rule:

```
div.main-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Which is being imported by *something* in the kniting/generation process, not sure what.

But Rmd allows you to add your own CSS rules. So you can overwrite the problematic rule with this rule taking advantage of [CSS's !important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```
div.main-container {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

In a file named "styles.css" located in the same directory as your Rmd file. Then reference the CSS file in your front-matter (YAML header):

```
title: "Example SO"                                                        
output:                                                                    
  html_document:                                                           
    toc: true                                                              
    number_sections: true                                                  
    code_folding: "hide"                                                   
    toc_float:                                                             
      collapse: false                                                      
      smooth_scroll: false
    css: styles.css
```

You will get a result with the contents shifted all the way to the left edge of the browser.

[image]

This is one path to get to your request of "no wasted space", but there are lots of other routes if you really want left-justified but fixed width content.

If you want to "soak up the space between the TOC table and the content block you could add this to 'style.css'

```
.tocify {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
.toc-content {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: That's great already. For some reason the space between the TOC and the text is actually different when I use the css you suggested. Any idea on how I can control this ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the space in between. If you want to expand the TOC out to "soak" up that space you could do something like my edit

Comment: well I'd like the distance between TOC and text to be constant bug lower than what it is now

Comment: the `padding-left: ` is probably what you want to tweak

Comment: Sometimes I see ```{css sidenote, echo = FALSE}, div.tocify" and sometimes ```{css sidenote, echo = FALSE}, .tocify" (without the 'div'). Is there a difference?